# How to copy a file from the jar at runtime?

Tags: java, jar, runtime

I would to copy a file from my src file in my project to my dir, but its not working when I exported to runnable jar.

```
      public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        FileCopyController fpc = new FileCopyController();
        File fileSrc = new File("src/java.exe");
        File fileDest = new File("C:/Directory1/java.exe");
        fpc.copyFileUsingChannel(fileSrc, fileDest);
     }

     public  void copyFileUsingChannel(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
     InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(source);
            os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
            os.close();
        }
```

Comment: JAR usually do not contain the sources. If your JAR contains the file needed, you could use a class loader to locate it for you, so that you could open/copy it....

Comment: can u give me an example thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    final InputStrean src = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/java.exe");
    final Path dest = new File("C:/Directory1/java.exe").toPath();
    Files.copy(src, dest, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```